# Can you put pygame projects into an online format

Tags: python, html, pygame

A while ago, I got really interested in pygame because of the ease of coding and fun
results it offered. The problem then was this: My friends use mac computers and packaging the pygame into an exe was impractical, so I wondered "Could I put these games online?". I spent hours searching and finally came up with a website that had some simple games and claimed they were pygame-run. If any of you can tell me if this is possible, please tell me. I only want to make simple 2d games. :)

Comment: Perhaps if you linked the website, it would be easier to confirm or debunk its claims.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run PyGame in browser.

Browsers can run HTML+CSS+JS or Flash and PyGame doesn't generate HTML or Flash

`Exe` is good for Windows. Current MacOS is base on Unix (probably FreeBSD) and friend can install python and pygame like on Unix or Linux to run `.py` files.

As a Linux use I could say MacOS is better system for Python then Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Today, i'd recommand using pygbag https://pypi.org/project/pygbag/ from https://pygame-web.github.io. It is using Web Assembly for modern browsers and allow for runing pygame and official CPython code with minimal modifications.